# removeObserver not working for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification IOS

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

Hi I am developing iPhone application in which I am registering for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification for notification. But when I tried to unregister that observer then its not working. It still get called. My code looks like

in viewDidLoad method I am registering like this

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(applicationBecomeActive)
 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
 object:nil];
```

And on my logout method I tried to remove this observer like this

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification];
```

but this is not working. Am I doing some thing wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're not removing the observer.

Notice your add observer method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(applicationBecomeActive)
 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
 object:nil];
```

The important part is addObserver:self

So in order to remove the observer, you do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

or if you only want to remove it for a particular notification name:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
       name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: So if I remove only observer without specifying name then it will not listen for all other notifications as well right?

Comment: If you removeObserver:self, you'll remove it for all the notifications.

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer so others can see that your question is resolved.